# Update issues with Compiled Vim Version

Tags: vim, compilation, debian

Good evening =)

I'm having some trouble with my vim and Debian Stretch. I compiled vim by myself (and it's working properly), but I'm going through some problems with updates. My apt package override my vim installation with apt .deb package.
I'm not sure how I can change debian/rules to avoid updating it, unfortunately =/.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem: The apt tool will install Debian's `*.deb` packages into `/usr/bin/vim` (runtime information in `/usr/share/vim`, etc.), whereas the default compilation options place the Vim binary in `/usr/local/bin/vim`. That's how it's supposed to be: Locally compiled stuff goes into `/usr/local/`, and therefore doesn't clash with installed packages. (You have to put `/usr/local/bin` near the beginning of `PATH` to get the locally compiled versions.)

Please check your configuration options; I suspect you've supplied `--prefix=/usr` to the `./configure` call. That's wrong.

Comment: I completely forgot --prefix during compilation, my bad and thanks for the help =D

Comment: Ah, glad I could help! Please accept the answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark. This way, the question is marked as closed, and you increase your chances of getting answers to future questions, as this shows that you care about the answers.